# JavaScript get the element in array of object

Tags: javascript

I have 2 Array:

```
const arr1 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "a"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "ab"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "abc"
}]
```

and

```
const arr2 = [{id:"1"}, {id:"3"}]
```

How can i get from two above array to get the result like that:

```
const result = ["a", "abc"]
```

I'm struggling with array built-in function. Thank you for reading.

Comment: why do you have mixed values like strings and numbers for `id`? have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following.

```js
const arr1 = [{ id: 1, name: "a"}, {id: 2, name: "ab"}, { id: 3, name: "abc" }]
const arr2 = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 3 }];

const ids = arr2.map(item => item.id);
const includedIds = arr1.filter(item => ids.includes(item.id)).map(item => item.id)

console.log(includedIds)
```